# the use of import (important) not "of import"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I have had a lot of trouble finding an answer on this, mainly because searching for import obviously has far more results for the other meaning.

The few results I have found always give examples of the word "import" in the context "of import". For example; He was a man of import; It was of great import that they arrive on time. etc.

I realise that import could be considered archaic, but can it be used without the word "of"?

For example; he was obsessed with his own import; He was attracted by her import. etc.

Comment: _Import_ in the sense of _meaning, significance_ can be used without being preceded by _of_ (Oxford gives the example 'the import of her message is clear'), but your two examples don't make sense. Import isn't something you can find attractive.

Comment: @KateBunting Surely somethings significance is an attractive or unattractive property. It is not unusual for someone to be attracted to someone of importance. In some of those cases you may be able to say they were attracted to the importance and not the person?

Comment: Yes, but we don't use _import_ to refer to a person's importance in the sense of high social status. You could say _He was attracted by her air of importance._ The _import_ of something is its significance to some serious issue.

Comment: Unless you have a particular reason, then *importance* is the usual word. *Import* has a whiff of the literary or maybe archaic, and if you don't know the difference and aren't aiming for a particular effect, use the common word.

Comment: Import in this sense means "important".  It's no longer commonly used, mainly archaic, or found in older literature. I suggest you don't use it unless it's for effect.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't say this.

A person doesn't have **import**. A person might be assigned a level of importance based on their position in a hierarchy, but the word is **importance** and it's not abbreviated.